# Improve table layout

Tags: tables, booktabs

any ideas about how to improve this table layout? IMHO it looks horrible.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\toprule
\bfseries{Grandezza}&\bfseries{\makecell{Unità di \\ misura}}&\(\boldsymbol{t_a}\)&\(\boldsymbol{t_d}\)&\(\boldsymbol{t_p}\)&\bfseries{RMS}&\bfseries{Picco}\\ \hline \\[-1em]
\(\Delta t_i\)  &   \(s\)   &   0.2 & 0.2   &   0.3 &   &\\ \hline \\[-1em]
\(\dot{\theta}_{C}^{MAX}\)  &   \(rad/s\)   & 7.85  & 7.85 & 0  &  & 7.85 \\ 
\hline \\[-1em]
\(\overline{\dot{\theta}}_{C}\) &   \(rad/s\)   & 3.93  & 3.93  & 0 & 3.43 & 
\\ \hline \\[-1em]
 \(\ddot{\theta}_{C}^{MAX}\)& \(rad/s^{2}\) &   39.3 & -39.3    &   0 & 29.7 & 39.3 \\ \hline \\[-1em]
\(J_t\cdot\ddot{\theta}_{C}\)& \(Nm\)   & 66.81 &-66.81 & 0 &   & \\ \hline \\[-1em]
\(C_c\) & \(Nm\)&   1.4 &   1.4 &   0 & & \\ \hline \\[-1em]
\(C_{pd}\) & \(Nm\)  &  0.3 &   0 & 0 & & \\ \hline \\[-1em]
\(C_v^{Picco}\) & \(Nm\) &  1.57 &  1.57  & 0 & & \\ \hline \\[-1em]
\(C_v^{Medio}\) & \(Nm\) &  0.79 &  0.79  & 0 & & \\ \hline \\[-1em]
\(C_R^{Picco}\) & \(Nm\) &  3.27 &  2.97  & 0 & & \\ \hline \\[-1em]
\(T_{2}^{Picco}\)&\(Nm\)    & 70.1  & -63.8 & 0 &   & 70.1 \\ \hline \\[-1em]
\(T_{2}^{Media}\)&\(Nm\)    & 69.3  & -64.6 & 0 & 50.7  &  \\ \hline \\[-1em]
Tipo di moto & - &  Dir. & Retr. & - &  & \\ \hline \\[-1em]
&   &   &   &   &   & \\ \hline \\[-1em]
&   &   &   &   &   & \\ \hline \\[-1em]
&   &   &   &   &   & \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabella riassuntiva per il dimensionamento del riduttore della tavola rotante}
\label{tab:dimensionamento_tavola_rotante}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're definitely right ;)

Comment: rules from `booktabs` and vertical lines are not intend to work together ...

Comment: I need vertical lines so, what's your suggestion?

Comment: @Zarko: It is possible to remove the spacing above horizontal rules from `booktabs` to 'enable' vertical rules, but in this case, `booktabs` could be dropped anyway.

Comment: For the units like `Nm`  you could use `\usepackage{siunitx}` and `\si{\newton\metre}` instead

Comment: Ok, this is a good starting point.

Comment: If you prefer having lots of horizontal and vertical lines, you must like the "prison cell" aesthetic...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, i know, that it is possible to reduce vertical space around bootktabs' rules. my comment should also contain ".. on the way as you use ..."

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd19G.png

Comment: please have a look at https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/ and https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf

Comment: @samcarter: That's the real cause the `tikzducks` package has been made for, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You got me :)

Comment: As you seem to require vertical and horizontal lines, which make tables look horrible, I think that you should have said so in your question and have saved several people their efforts in removing them.

Comment: Units should not be written in italics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some more improvements and simplification of the table code. For a caption width equal to the table width, the simplest is to use the `threeparttable` environment, which measures this width. Also, I replaced `\overline{\dot{\theta}}` in the first line with `\widebar{\dot{\theta}}`, borrowed from the `mathabx` font package, which takes into account that maths Greek letters are italic.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, italian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\rd{\radian}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries\boldmath}
\newcommand{\colhead}[1]{{\small\bfseries\boldmath#1}}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering\sisetup{per-mode = symbol, table-format = 2.2, table-number-alignment = center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\rowcolors{2}{WhiteSmoke!80!Lavender}{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}
\begin{tabular}{ >{$}l<{$}cSS[table-format=-2.2]S[table-format=1.1]SS}
\rowcolor{SlateGray!40}
\textbf{\small Grandezza} & \thead{Unità di\\misura}& \colhead{$t_a$} & \colhead{$t_d$} & \colhead{$t_p$}
& \colhead{RMS} & \colhead{Picco} \\
 \Delta t_i & \si{\second} & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.3 & &\\
\dot{\theta}_{C}^{\max} & \si{\rd\per\s} & 7.85 & 7.85 & 0 & & 7.85 \\
\widebar{\dot{\theta}}_{C} & \si{\rd\per\s} & 3.93 & 3.93 & 0 & 3.43 & \\
\ddot{\theta}_{C}^{\max} & \si{\rd\per\square\s} & 39.3 & -39.3 & 0 & 29.7 & 39.3 \\
J_t\cdot\ddot{\theta}_{C} & \si{\N\m} & 66.81 & -66.81 & 0 & & \\
C_c & \si{\N\m}& 1.4 & 1.4 & 0 & & \\
C_\text{pd} & \si{\N\m} & 0.3 & 0 & 0 & & \\
C_v^\text{Picco} & \si{\N\m} & 1.57 & 1.57 & 0 & & \\
C_v^\text{Medio} & \si{\N\m} & 0.79 & 0.79 & 0 & & \\
C_R^\text{Picco} & \si{\N\m} & 3.27 & 2.97 & 0 & & \\
T_{2}^\text{Picco} &\si{\N\m} & 70.1 & -63.8 & 0 & & 70.1 \\
T_{2}^\text{Media} &\si{\N\m} & 69.3 & -64.6 & 0 & 50.7 & \\
\text{Tipo di moto} & -- & {Dir.} & {Retr.} & {--} & & \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabella riassuntiva per il dimensionamento del riduttore della tavola rotante}
\label{tab:dimensionamento_tavola_rotante}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: I've updated – and added the precision that the *table* code was simplified ;o)

Answer (score 12):

Some suggestions:

- Fewer, but better spaced horizontal lines
- No vertical lines. None!
- Use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment.
- Use `\si` for the units
- Use `S` column type for the numeric columns

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,amsmath,siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{} lc S[table-format=2.2]
                      S[table-format=-2.2]
                      S[table-format=1.1]
                      S[table-format=2.2]
                      S[table-format=2.2] @{}}
\toprule
\text{\bfseries Grandezza}&
\makecell{\text{\bfseries Unità di}\\ \text{\bfseries misura}}&
{\boldsymbol{t_a}} &
{\boldsymbol{t_d}} &
{\boldsymbol{t_p}} &
{\text{\bfseries RMS}} &
{\text{\bfseries Picco}}\\ 
\midrule
\Delta t_i  & \si{\second} &   0.2 & 0.2   &   0.3 &   &\\  
\dot{\theta}_{C}^{\mathrm{MAX}} & \si{\radian\per\second} & 7.85 & 7.85 & 0  &  & 7.85 \\ 
\bar{\dot{\theta}}_{C}          & \si{\radian\per\second} & 3.93 & 3.93  & 0 & 3.43 & \\  
\ddot{\theta}_{C}^{\mathrm{MAX}}& \si{\radian\per\second\squared}& 39.3 & -39.3 & 0 & 29.7 & 39.3 \\  
J_t\cdot\ddot{\theta}_{C}& \si{\newton\meter} & 66.81 &-66.81 & 0 & & \\  
C_c                      & \si{\newton\meter}  &   1.4 &   1.4 &   0 & & \\  
C_{pd}                   & \si{\newton\meter} &  0.3 &   0 & 0 & & \\  
C_v^{\mathrm{Picco}}     & \si{\newton\meter} &  1.57 &  1.57  & 0 & & \\  
C_v^{\mathrm{Medio}}     & \si{\newton\meter} &  0.79 &  0.79  & 0 & & \\  
C_R^{\mathrm{Picco}}     & \si{\newton\meter} &  3.27 &  2.97  & 0 & & \\  
T_{2}^{\mathrm{Picco}}   & \si{\newton\meter} & 70.1  & -63.8 & 0 &   & 70.1 \\  
T_{2}^{\mathrm{Media}}   & \si{\newton\meter} & 69.3  & -64.6 & 0 & 50.7  &  \\  
\text{Tipo di moto}      & \text{--}          & {\text{Dir.}} & {\text{Retr.}} & \text{--} & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\caption{Tabella riassuntiva per il dimensionamento del riduttore della tavola rotante}
\label{tab:dimensionamento_tavola_rotante}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is nice, but i prefer to have vertical and horizontal lines and moreover number are not aligned

Comment: @iacopo Why do you thing the numbers are not aligned? They are aligned at the decimal marker.

Comment: @iacopo Vertical lines are a typographical sin. Horizontal rules are, too, when they serve no purpose; the only needed ones here are top, after header, bottom. The last line is quite mysterious: probably an explanation in the caption (or as a note to the table, after the bottom rule) that `\tau_a` refers to direct motion and `\tau_d` to retrograde motion is better.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one version (without vertical rules although you like them). Further improvements:

- typesetting units with `siunitx` (you can use it's options to change appearance)
- aligning the columns left where possible and number columns at the decimal marker
- adjusted the vertical spacing (your leftmost column is a vertical monster)

What you could consider:

- changing the caption width to table width
- making the number of decimal places consistent

[image: table]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{tabular}{llS[table-format=2.2]SSS[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=2.2]}
\toprule
Grandezza & Unità di & $t_a$ & {$t_d$} & $t_p$ & {RMS} & {Picco}\\[-.4em]
& misura & & & & &\\\midrule
\(\Delta t_i\)  &   \si{\second}   &   0.2 & 0.2   &   0.3 &   &\\
\(\dot{\theta}_{C}^{MAX}\)  &   \si{\radian\per\second}   & 7.85  & 7.85 & 0  &  & 7.85 \\ 
\(\overline{\dot{\theta}}_{C}\) &   \si{\radian\per\second}   & 3.93  & 3.93  & 0 & 3.43 & \\
 \(\ddot{\theta}_{C}^{MAX}\)& \si{\radian\per\square\second} &   39.3 & -39.3    &   0 & 29.7 & 39.3 \\
\(J_t\cdot\ddot{\theta}_{C}\)& \si{\newton\metre}   & 66.81 & -66.81 & 0 &   & \\
\(C_c\) & \si{\newton\metre}&   1.4 &   1.4 &   0 & & \\
\(C_{pd}\) & \si{\newton\metre}  &  0.3 &   0 & 0 & & \\
\(C_v^{Picco}\) & \si{\newton\metre} &  1.57 &  1.57  & 0 & & \\
\(C_v^{Medio}\) & \si{\newton\metre} &  0.79 &  0.79  & 0 & & \\ 
\(C_R^{Picco}\) & \si{\newton\metre} &  3.27 &  2.97  & 0 & & \\
\(T_{2}^{Picco}\)&\si{\newton\metre}    & 70.1  & -63.8 & 0 &   & 70.1 \\
\(T_{2}^{Media}\)&\si{\newton\metre}    & 69.3  & -64.6 & 0 & 50.7  &  \\
Tipo di moto & -- &  {Dir.} & {Retr.} & {--} &  & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabella riassuntiva per il dimensionamento del riduttore della tavola rotante}
\label{tab:dimensionamento_tavola_rotante}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Edit:* Here's a version with "horizontal rules" that does not look too awful.

[image: colored]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
\rowcolors{2}{black!2}{gray!20}
\begin{tabular}{llS[table-format=2.2]SSS[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=2.2]}
\rowcolor{gray!40}Grandezza & Unità di & $t_a$ & {$t_d$} & $t_p$ & {RMS} & {Picco}\\[-.4em]
\rowcolor{gray!40}& misura & & & & &\\
\(\Delta t_i\)  &   \si{\second}   &   0.2 & 0.2   &   0.3 &   &\\
\(\dot{\theta}_{C}^{MAX}\)  &   \si{\radian\per\second}   & 7.85  & 7.85 & 0  &  & 7.85 \\ 
\(\overline{\dot{\theta}}_{C}\) &   \si{\radian\per\second}   & 3.93  & 3.93  & 0 & 3.43 & \\
 \(\ddot{\theta}_{C}^{MAX}\)& \si{\radian\per\square\second} &   39.3 & -39.3    &   0 & 29.7 & 39.3 \\
\(J_t\cdot\ddot{\theta}_{C}\)& \si{\newton\metre}   & 66.81 & -66.81 & 0 &   & \\
\(C_c\) & \si{\newton\metre}&   1.4 &   1.4 &   0 & & \\
\(C_{pd}\) & \si{\newton\metre}  &  0.3 &   0 & 0 & & \\
\(C_v^{Picco}\) & \si{\newton\metre} &  1.57 &  1.57  & 0 & & \\
\(C_v^{Medio}\) & \si{\newton\metre} &  0.79 &  0.79  & 0 & & \\ 
\(C_R^{Picco}\) & \si{\newton\metre} &  3.27 &  2.97  & 0 & & \\
\(T_{2}^{Picco}\)&\si{\newton\metre}    & 70.1  & -63.8 & 0 &   & 70.1 \\
\(T_{2}^{Media}\)&\si{\newton\metre}    & 69.3  & -64.6 & 0 & 50.7  &  \\
Tipo di moto & -- &  {Dir.} & {Retr.} & {--} &  & \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabella riassuntiva per il dimensionamento del riduttore della tavola rotante}
\label{tab:dimensionamento_tavola_rotante}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, this is a good version but i need vertical and horizontal lines

Comment: @iacopo You asked for good-looking. I've added a compromise with "horizontal rules" (kind of).

Answer (score 2):

like this:

[image]

what is ugly is meter of personal taste (personally i don't like vertical lines, but you insist to have them ...). at least the code for above table is more correct ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\theadgape}{}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|>{$}l<{$}|
                s|
           *{3}{S[table-format=-2.2]|}
                S[table-format= 2.2]|
                S[table-format= 2.1]|
                }
    \Xhline{1pt}
\thead[b]{\text{Grandezza}}
    &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\thead[b]{Unità di \\ misura}}
        &   {\thead[b]{$t_a$}}
            &   {\thead[b]{$t_d$}}
                &   {\thead[b]{$t_p$}}
                    &   {\thead[b]{RMS}}
                        &   {\thead[b]{Picco}}                                      \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
\Delta t_i                  &   s           &  0.2  &  0.2  & 0.3   &       &       \\  \hline
\dot{\theta}_{C}^{\max}     &   rad/s       &  7.85 &  7.85 & 0     &       & 7.85  \\  \hline
\overline{\dot{\theta}}_{C} &   rad/s       &  3.93 &  3.93 & 0     &  3.43 &       \\  \hline
\ddot{\theta}_{C}^{\max}    &   rad/s^{2}   & 39.3  & -39.3 & 0     & 29.7  & 39.3  \\  \hline
J_t\cdot\ddot{\theta}_{C}   &   Nm          & 66.81 & -66.81& 0     &       &       \\  \hline
C_c                         &   Nm          &   1.4 &   1.4 & 0     &       &       \\  \hline
C_{pd}                      &   Nm          &  0.3  &   0   & 0     &       &       \\  \hline
C_v^{\mathrm{Picco}}        &   Nm          &  1.57 &  1.57 & 0     &       &       \\  \hline
C_v^{\mathrm{Medio}}        &   Nm          &  0.79 &  0.79 & 0     &       &       \\  \hline
C_R^{\mathrm{Picco}}        &   Nm          &  3.27 &  2.97 & 0     &       &       \\  \hline
T_{2}^{\mathrm{Picco}}      &   Nm          & 70.1  & -63.8 & 0     &       & 70.1  \\  \hline
T_{2}^{\mathrm{Media}}      &   Nm          & 69.3  & -64.6 & 0     & 50.7  &       \\  \hline
\text{Tipo di moto}         &   {-}         & {Dir.}&{Retr.}& {--}  &       &       \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Tabella riassuntiva per il dimensionamento del riduttore della tavola rotante}
    \label{tab:dimensionamento_tavola_rotante}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May it be that the end of the code is missing?

Comment: yes, i lost it in copy/past process ... (we still have holydays :-)). corrected now. happy new year!

Comment: This is good, i know horizontal rules are not nice to see but i need them for educational purposes. Can you align the numbers btw? Thank you! And happy new year of course!

Comment: numbers are aligned. at decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another suggestion with vertical and less horizontal lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|S[table-format=2.2]|S[table-format=-2.2]|S[table-format=1.1]|S[table-format=2.2]|S[table-format=2.2]}
\hline
\bfseries{Grandezza}&\bfseries{\makecell{Unità di \\ misura}}&\(\boldsymbol{t_a}\)&\(\boldsymbol{t_d}\)&\(\boldsymbol{t_p}\)&\bfseries{RMS}&\bfseries{Picco}\\\hline
\(\Delta t_i\)  &   \si{\s}   &   0.2 & 0.2   &   0.3 &   &\\ 
\(\dot{\theta}_{C}^{MAX}\)  &  \si{\radian\per\s}  & 7.85  & 7.85 & 0  &  & 7.85 \\ 

\(\overline{\dot{\theta}}_{C}\) &   \si{\radian\per\s}   & 3.93  & 3.93  & 0 & 3.43 & 
\\ 
 \(\ddot{\theta}_{C}^{MAX}\)& \si{\radian\per\s\square} &   39.3 & -39.3    &   0 & 29.7 & 39.3 \\ \hline
\(J_t\cdot\ddot{\theta}_{C}\)& \si{\newton\metre}   & 66.81 &-66.81 & 0 &   & \\ 
\(C_c\) & \si{\newton\metre}&   1.4 &   1.4 &   0 & & \\ 
\(C_{pd}\) & \si{\newton\metre}  &  0.3 &   0 & 0 & & \\ 
\(C_v^{Picco}\) & \si{\newton\metre} &  1.57 &  1.57  & 0 & & \\ \hline
\(C_v^{Medio}\) & \si{\newton\metre} &  0.79 &  0.79  & 0 & & \\ 
\(C_R^{Picco}\) & \si{\newton\metre} &  3.27 &  2.97  & 0 & & \\ 
\(T_{2}^{Picco}\)& \si{\newton\metre}    & 70.1  & -63.8 & 0 &   & 70.1 \\
\(T_{2}^{Media}\)& \si{\newton\metre}   & 69.3  & -64.6 & 0 & 50.7  &  \\ \hline
Tipo di moto & - &  {Dir.} & {Retr.} & {-} &  & \\ 
&   &   &   &   &   & \\
&   &   &   &   &   & \\
&   &   &   &   &   & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabella riassuntiva per il dimensionamento del riduttore della tavola rotante}
\label{tab:dimensionamento_tavola_rotante}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Markus Püschel's excellent [Small Guide to Making Nice Tables](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf).